# Prototype inheritance vs reference, performance in node/V8

Tags: javascript, v8

I have a large collection (near 1 million) of objects organized in a tree/hierarchy using parent/children properties as references, such as:

```
{
  parent: x, // reference to parent object.
  children: [], // containing child objects.
}
```

They also share a common context object.

One way is to pass the context object to every object. The other way is to make all of them inherits from the context object.

I wonder if there is dramatic difference in performance, in terms of speed and memory usage, in V8? Should I prefer one to the other?

The tree topology is not changed frequently. But the tree are visited frequently, and when visiting a node, some methods of context object will be accessed.

Comment: [Why don't _you_ tell _us_ which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You could also consider not storing the context on the tree nodes at all, but passing it in to the visitor function separately. Not saying it's better, just an alternative to think about.

Comment: Why are those methods on the context object, not on the node itself? Or is the context used elsewhere as well, or has its own mutable properties? Do you have multiple different contexts in your application? If yes, could every tree have a different context, or every node?

Comment: Yes, it's reasonable to expect that sharing the property on the prototype has a memory usage benefit for that many objects. You should try it and measure the difference, and check for speed regressions.